# Qt 5.9.5 on Ubuntu can't find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm" despite drivers being installed

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, cmake

When trying to build a piece Qt software, I get an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:9 (message):
  Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:184 (include)
  build/FindQt5.cmake:32 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:87 (include)
```

All the solutions to this error that I've found are to run `sudo apt install mesa-common-dev`, but this is something I've already done with no positive effect:

```
mesa-common-dev is already the newest version (20.0~git1912130730.828f8f~oibaf~b).
```

Could the fact that I'm using a third-party graphics driver library ([oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)) be the cause for this?

Other things I've tried include symlinking the only other `gl.h` file that occurs (`/usr/include/hwlock/gl.h`) to the location Qt is searching at, but that only creates more errors.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, using Qt installed from the Ubuntu apt repos. Any help is very much appreciated; this is driving me round the bend.

Comment: install `libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: Thanks, but `libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (20.0~git1912130730.828f8f~oibaf~b)`

Comment: You can use `apt-file` to locate packages providing those files. You can use `apt-get` to install dependencies required for building a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oibaf seemed to be the problem. After running `sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`, everything is back in the right place and I can build.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: As I clearly said in the comments, `libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version (20.0~git1912130730.828f8f~oibaf~b)`.

Comment: While trying to build the code from -     https://github.com/jasondegraw/Qt-CMake-HelloWorld I faced similar error with message - . <pre>    Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm".    </pre>.Using the above sudo install suggestion solved my problem. I am using Ubuntu xenial.